# Attemping to Remove Lines from Text File

Tags: c#, text-files

I have created a text file that stores different flight information. I want the admins to be able to remove flights from this page by clicking a 'remove' button associated. I have the following code:

```
    private void removeButtons()
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < buttons.Count(); x++)
        {
            Button booked = buttons[x];
            booked.Click += new EventHandler(removeFlights);
        }
    }

    private void removeFlights(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string tempFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(AppendTexts.flightPathText))//Location of file
        {
            using (var sw = new StreamWriter(tempFile))
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    String[] flights = line.Split(',');
                    for (int x = 0; x < buttons.Count(); x++)//If the button clicked matches all the fields, skip it, otherwise write it to temp file
                    {
                        if (airline[0].Text == flights[0] & price[x].Text == flights[1] & cityStartMatch[x].Text == flights[2] & stateStartMatch[x].Text == flights[3] &
                            cityDestMatch[x].Text == flights[4] & stateDestMatch[x].Text == flights[5] & seatsMatch[x].Text == flights[6] & dateMatch[x].Text == flights[7])
                        {

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            sw.WriteLine(flights[0] + "," + flights[1] + "," + flights[2] + "," + flights[3] + "," + flights[4] + "," + flights[5] + "," + flights[6] + "," +  flights[7]);
                        }
                    }
                }
                sr.Close();
            }
        }
        File.Delete(AppendTexts.flightPathText);
        File.Move(tempFile, AppendTexts.flightPathText);
    }
```

The problem I am having, is that instead of removing the old lines, it just re-adds the other ones to the file. So if I have a flight using the Delta airline and another using Southwest, and I attempt to remove the Delta airline, when I list the flights again, the Delta airline shows up once, but the Southwest airline shows up twice.

Comment: I find your code hard to read. At a glance, you're using the bitwise operator `&`, instead of the logical AND operator `&&`, but it's hard to read close enough into it to see if that's the only problem you're having. If you could make your code a little more readable, I could be more helpful.

Comment: Yup, code otherwise looks good.  No real explanation.  Everybody starts with text files, flip the ignore bit on that.

Answer (score 1):

A. Using a text file as a database in a bad practice.

B. When deleting multiple values from a collection,
either use a temporary collection that you write
good value to.
Then delete original collection and overwrite with temp one.
Or... Delete in-place from end to beginning,
so that current index is not messed up by deleted.
(Use of temp file is more recommended when deleting from large text files,
in the second method you also have to keep reducing file size.)

C. In your solution, you didn't change position
to correct one, calculsted relative to beginning of file, before each write
(and readjust before each read).

Answer (score 0):

Databases are great, really useful for this sort of application, and will greatly improve your applications.

I'm a developer by trade, and spend about 20 / 30% of my time writing SQL (database language), and really this is what you should be using for a ASP.NET app or any web app for that matter.

Once you learn it and start using it fully, you'll wonder how you ever did without it.

Comment: Would it be difficult to convert my program over from text files to actual databases? If not, how would I go about doing it? I'm using Visual Studio and I know it has built in local databases, but how do I set them up and connect to them?

Comment: If you want to stick with microsoft, you can download MS SQL from the Microsoft Web Platform - installer software.  

Check out: http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/install-and-configure-sql-server-2008-express - for installation instructions.  And then go about learning SQL, I know this sounds like a big task, but you can ask questions on this forum, do a bit of a google search and I'm not sure of the netiquet - but I guess you can continue to ask about it on this post.  It is an important thing to learn though.

I'm more than happy to help - it'll help me with my ratings - :)